# What to do to get the "Curious" badge with a negative score question?

Tags: support, questions, voting, badges

Source post: [Villagers still not breeding](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/228098/villagers-still-not-breeding)

I got a small problem for getting the "Curious" badge because this question has a -1 score and the "Need a positive question record" requirement isn't met. Also, it got lots of comments and an answer, so deleting won't be nice. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't affect it, I don't think your five questions have to be done one after the other for the badge.

Comment: The "Need a positive question record" condition isn't met. @GnomeSlice

Answer (score 3):

The Curious Badge is based on your overall net score - a single question at -1 shouldn't have any material effect.

Comment: No. See the [link](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/117102/John) of my account and please tell me why is the "Need a positive question record" condition not met.